# @Email validation-annotation leads to NullPointerException in deployment

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, validation, wildfly

I'm getting a NullPointerException during the deployment of my Wildfly 13 Server. It seems like this only happens when I'm using the `@Email` annotation.
It works fine if I run the following code without it. Do you have any Ideas on how to fix this?

```
@GET
@Path("/register")
@PermitAll
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response register(@QueryParam("email") @Email @Unique(UserEmailUniqueConfirmer.class) String email, @QueryParam("password") @NotEmpty String password) {
    try {
        authenticationService.register(email, password);
        return Response.ok().build();

    } catch (UserEmailAlreadyInUseException e) {
        return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
    }
}
```

**Maven Dependencies**

```
<dependency> <!-- EE ORM implementation -->
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.3.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency><!-- EE EntityManager implementation -->
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.3.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency> <!-- EE Validation implementation -->
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.11.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Wildfly Log**

```
15:05:01,938 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."test-server-1.0.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."test-server-1.0.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1728)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1556)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.reflect.annotation.TypeAnnotationParser.mapTypeAnnotations(TypeAnnotationParser.java:356)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotatedTypeFactory$AnnotatedTypeBaseImpl.<init>(AnnotatedTypeFactory.java:139)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotatedTypeFactory.buildAnnotatedType(AnnotatedTypeFactory.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.TypeAnnotationParser.buildAnnotatedTypes(TypeAnnotationParser.java:137)
    at java.lang.reflect.Executable.getAnnotatedParameterTypes(Executable.java:688)
    at java.lang.reflect.Parameter.getAnnotatedType(Parameter.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.TypeAnnotationAwareMetaDataProvider.findTypeAnnotationConstraintsForExecutableParameter(TypeAnnotationAwareMetaDataProvider.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.getParameterMetaData(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:498)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.findExecutableMetaData(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:347)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.getMetaData(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:332)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.getMethodMetaData(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:318)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.retrieveBeanConfiguration(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.getBeanConfiguration(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.getBeanConfigurationForHierarchy(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.BeanMetaDataManager.createBeanMetaData(BeanMetaDataManager.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.BeanMetaDataManager.getOrCreateBeanMetaData(BeanMetaDataManager.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.BeanMetaDataManager.getBeanMetaData(BeanMetaDataManager.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.getConstraintsForClass(ValidatorImpl.java:327)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.ValidationExtension.determineConstrainedCallables(ValidationExtension.java:241)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.ValidationExtension.processAnnotatedType(ValidationExtension.java:228)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:95)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:85)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInvocationStrategy$SimpleMethodInvocationStrategy.invoke(MethodInvocationStrategy.java:129)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:330)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.java:123)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:308)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:286)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.ContainerLifecycleEvents.fireProcessAnnotatedType(ContainerLifecycleEvents.java:203)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.ContainerLifecycleEvents.fireProcessAnnotatedType(ContainerLifecycleEvents.java:174)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.processAnnotatedTypes(BeanDeployer.java:166)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.createTypes(BeanDeployment.java:219)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.startInitialization(WeldStartup.java:415)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.startInitialization(WeldBootstrap.java:79)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:95)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1736)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1698)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1556)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.ContainerLifecycleEvents.fireProcessAnnotatedType(ContainerLifecycleEvents.java:210)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.ContainerLifecycleEvents.fireProcessAnnotatedType(ContainerLifecycleEvents.java:174)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.processAnnotatedTypes(BeanDeployer.java:166)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.createTypes(BeanDeployment.java:219)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.startInitialization(WeldStartup.java:415)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.startInitialization(WeldBootstrap.java:79)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:95)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1736)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1698)
    ... 6 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at sun.reflect.annotation.TypeAnnotationParser.mapTypeAnnotations(TypeAnnotationParser.java:356)
            at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotatedTypeFactory$AnnotatedTypeBaseImpl.<init>(AnnotatedTypeFactory.java:139)
            at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotatedTypeFactory.buildAnnotatedType(AnnotatedTypeFactory.java:65)
            at sun.reflect.annotation.TypeAnnotationParser.buildAnnotatedTypes(TypeAnnotationParser.java:137)
            at java.lang.reflect.Executable.getAnnotatedParameterTypes(Executable.java:688)
            at java.lang.reflect.Parameter.getAnnotatedType(Parameter.java:237)
            at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.TypeAnnotationAwareMetaDataProvider.findTypeAnnotationConstraintsForExecutableParameter(TypeAnnotationAwareMetaDataProvider.java:85)
            at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.getParameterMetaData(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:498)
            at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.findExecutableMetaData(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:347)
            at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.getMetaData(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:332)
            at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.getMethodMetaData(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:318)
            at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.retrieveBeanConfiguration(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:138)
            at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.getBeanConfiguration(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:125)
            at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.provider.AnnotationMetaDataProvider.getBeanConfigurationForHierarchy(AnnotationMetaDataProvider.java:108)
            at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.BeanMetaDataManager.createBeanMetaData(BeanMetaDataManager.java:203)
            at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.BeanMetaDataManager.getOrCreateBeanMetaData(BeanMetaDataManager.java:231)
            at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.BeanMetaDataManager.getBeanMetaData(BeanMetaDataManager.java:178)
            at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.getConstraintsForClass(ValidatorImpl.java:327)
            at org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.ValidationExtension.determineConstrainedCallables(ValidationExtension.java:241)
            at org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.ValidationExtension.processAnnotatedType(ValidationExtension.java:228)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:95)
            at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:85)
            at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInvocationStrategy$SimpleMethodInvocationStrategy.invoke(MethodInvocationStrategy.java:129)
            at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:330)
            at org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.java:123)
            at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:308)
            at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:286)
            at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.ContainerLifecycleEvents.fireProcessAnnotatedType(ContainerLifecycleEvents.java:203)
            ... 14 more
```

Comment: Do you have any [validation-api](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api) jars in the Wildfly server's classpath? If you find version `1.x` there, pls try to replace it with `2.0.1.Final` or try to downgrade hibernate validator to [5.4.2.Final](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.4.2.Final). I'd prefer the second solution. Pls make sure your app service is compatible with `javax-validation-2.x`. If it isn't then it's better to use `1.x` and  the corresponding `hibernate-validator` (which is `5.x`).

Comment: You may also try using standard `@javax.validation.constraints.Email`, I guess you have used `@org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure your Wildfly Server version is compatible with [JSR-380](https://beanvalidation.org/2.0/). The `hibernate-validator-6.x` uses `javax.validation:validation-api-2.0.x`.

Please check your server's classpath, if you find `javax.validation:validation-api-1.x` there, then you may try the following solutions:

1. Downgrade your hibernate validator to [version 5](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.4.2.Final) which is based on `javax.validation:validation-api-1.1.Final`
2. Upgrade your Wildfly Server to the new version which is compatible with new validation api. You may also try to replace validation api jars in your server classpath, but I'd prefer to use the official version if one available.

And remember to use standard `@javax.validation.constraints.Email` instead of the deprecated `@org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email` if you decide to use the JSR-380 and `hibernate-validator-6.x`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am already using the standard annotation but after I looked into the servers classpath i saw that wildfly by default runs in JEE7-Mode (which I knew but completely forgot right now). While it runs in JEE7-Mode it uses the `javax.validation:validation-api-1.1`. If I start the server with the following argument `-Dee8.preview.mode=true` it uses `javax.validation:validation-api-2.0.1` and the annotation can be used.